# bamboo not downloading PHP files

Tags: php, bamboo

the only thing I need bamboo to do, is fetch the files created by `artisan` and `composer`, which is in the `/` folder. It just **wont** do this.

my pattern is : `**/*.*` and the folder is `/`. but no matter what I do, it cant find the artifact..

`Unable to download artifact Shared artifact:`

What to do?